# Eigenvalue of multiplication of two matrix vs the eigenvalue of squared matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

$A$ and $B$ are two stochastic non-negative matrices. $B$ has the same value as $A$ but some rows and columns are displaced.

I was wondering if there is a way to proof: 
$\mathrm{SLEM}(A \cdot B) < \mathrm{SLEM}(A \cdot A)$

$\mathrm{SLEM}$ is second largest eigenvalue

Comment: Do you know that saying that $B$ results from $A$ by moving some rows and columns is equivalent to say that $B=P_1AP_2$ where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are certain permutation matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)?

Comment: @JeanMarie: What is it the connection of the eigenvalues of $AP_1AP_2$ and $AA$?

Comment: I haven't said I know a connection. I just indicated a standard way to put in matricial form the fact that you move rows ans columns.

Comment: as an example matrix A is :

Comment: as an example matrix A is : [1/3 1/3 1/3 0 0 0 0;1/3 1/3 1/3 0 0 0 0; 1/6 1/6 4/15 1/10 1/10 1/10 1/10 ; 0 0 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5; 0 0 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5;0 0 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5;0 0 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5 1/5;]

Comment: an example of matrix B is

Comment: 1/5 0 1/5 0 1/5 1/5 1/5

Comment: 0 1/3 1/3 1/3 0 0 0

Comment: 1/10 1/6 4/15 1/6 1/10 1/10 1/10

Comment: 0 1/3 1/3 1/3 0 0 0

Comment: 1/5 0 1/5 0 1/5 1/5 1/5

Comment: 1/5 0 1/5 0 1/5 1/5 1/5

Comment: 1/5 0 1/5 0 1/5 1/5 1/5

Comment: As you can see, the values didn't change and the change is only in their location.